# With XAMPP how to set a default homepage

Tags: xampp

My problem is when I set up a server with XAMPP the homepage is the content of the image below:

[image]

I have a file named html.html and a folder named hello in which there is another html file. As document root in httpd.conf I have the default c:/xampp/htdocs. I do not want to change the root of the website just set up a html homepage to be opened when someone joins the website.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named index.html in htdocs. This will compiled as default homepage.